# Rolling two dice

Tags: java, probability

I'm writing a program that is supposed to return the value of rolling two dice. I want the user to be able to select a specified type of die or chose a custom number of sides. So, for example, I chose the triangle die, I would have a 3 sided die.

The variable:

```
private int die = 1;
private int preselectedSides;
```

The case in a switch I've made to handle the menu looks like this:

```
switch(selection)
      case 1:
      premadeDice(3, 4, 6);
      x=1;
      break;
```

The receiving method looks like this:

```
//premade Dice Selection//
public int premadeDice(int triangle, int rectangle, int cube)
{         
    String choice;
    boolean flag = false;
    while (flag == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter in the shape you want your die to be");
        System.out.println("A triangle die has 3 sides. If this is what you want, type     \"triangle\"");
        System.out.println("A rectangle die has 4 sides. If this is what you want, type     \"rectangle\"");
        System.out.println("A cube die has 6 sides. If this is what you want, type     \"cube\"");
        choice = sc.next();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("triangle"))
        {
          System.out.println("You have chosen the triangle die."); 
          preselectedSides = triangle;
          flag = true;
        }

        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("rectangle"))
        {
          System.out.println("You have chosen the rectangle die."); 
          preselectedSides = rectangle;  
          flag = true;
        }

        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("cube"))
        {
          System.out.println("You have chosen the  traditonal cube die."); 
          preselectedSides = cube; 
          flag = true;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have not entered in a valid die shape. Try again");
        }
    }//end while loop

    return preselectedSides;

}//end pre-made dice method
```

I created a getter to get access to that returned value:

```
//getter for Die
public void getDie()
{
   System.out.println(preselectedSides);
}
```

Call it like this:

> test.getDie();

And I get the following output for a cube (or for the other shapes, I keep getting 1 along with the value)
1
6

I've tried finding this logic error but I don't see it. Why does it keep outputting the number one? **Ask for clarification if needed.**

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but a three-side polyhedron is an impossible object :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik OP didnt specify if this was a quantum computer =p

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's depthist. Here in Flatland we have plenty of D3s.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an awful lot of code.  You can simplify it like so:

```
public class Die  
{  
   int sides;
  //get/set/constructor  
   ...
}  


public class DieRoller  
{  
    Die die;  

    public int roll()  
    {  
       Random generator = new Random();  
       return generator.nextInt(this.die.getSides());
    }  
}
```

You can run it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    System.out.println("Number of sides?");  
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
    Die currentDie = new Die(sc.nextInt());  
    System.out.println("Rolling");
    DieRoller roller = new DieRoller(currentDie);  
    int sideRolled = roller.roll();  
    System.out.println(String.format("You rolled %d on your %d sided die",sideRolled,currentDie.getSides()));
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, I needed a sum for the particular die but that's an easy fix. Thanks.